# What word describes people who consciously choose to accept what is natural and not alter it

Tags: terminology, philosophy

Words that come to mind are:

- zen-like
- naturalist
- accepting

but perhaps there is a more scholarly/accurate/electric word I can publish.  These people are not ignorant or unable; they are reasonably intelligent, logical and capable, they just believe 'live and let live' is a better option than 'make the best of every situation.'

Comment: Depending on what "skew" you want, maybe ***fatalists*** or ***pragmatists***.

Comment: You could use nonchalant or insouciant.

Comment: I think you need to give an example sentence with your potential word, or these folks tend to close your question.

Comment: What's an electric word? Did you mean *eclectic* maybe?

Comment: @RegDwigнt make sure you put a 20A fuse on that word!

Comment: Also consider that you don't necessarily have to use a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Stoic** comes to mind.
There's an entry on [stoicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoicism) in Wikipedia:

> According to its teachings, as social beings, the path to eudaimonia
>   (happiness) for humans is found in accepting the moment as it presents
>   itself, by not allowing oneself to be controlled by the desire for
>   pleasure or fear of pain, by using one's mind to understand the world
>   and to do one's part in nature's plan, and by working together and
>   treating others fairly and justly.

Comment: Thank you!  It's not a very exciting word or active word, but it's a lot better than "accepting."  I'm also a bit surprised at that definition...I thought stoic was more apathetic then that...but that is why I'm asking these question--thanks for your help.

Comment: I think "stoic" is philosophically more aligned with discipline and neutrality, *achieved by*  acknowldging the wisdom of accepting whatever comes to pass. "Que sera sera". Webster puts it "free from passion [discipline], unmoved (emotionally)  [neutral], and then yes "submissive to natural law". Yes, it is apathetic (see definition 2: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, **Taoist**. Basically, 'before you build a bridge, ask is a bridge necessary in the first place,' and 'a tiger chooses to either strike or not strike, it does not fail to strike.'

We have -*ist*, -*ism*, and the root with no suffix at play (i.e., Taoist, Toaism, and *Tao*).

Wikipedia on **[Toaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao)**:

> *a [philosophy] which emphasizes living in harmony with the Tao*

And **[Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao)**:

> *Tao is the natural order of the universe whose character one’s human intuition must discern in order to realize the potential for individual wisdom. This intuitive knowing of “life” cannot be grasped as a concept; it is known through actual living experience of one’s everyday being.*

I think the [Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taoist) about long life and fortune through magic is suspect, but it is not really a **[secular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secular)** term. "Zen like" is very similar (via Buddhism). "Naturalist" I would say is not, its more like a green heart hippy vibe, idk. "Accepting" is just a gerund, cmon, now.

@FumbleFingers "fatalist" is also good.

Comment: Thanks for the word and definition, for me!  It does not fit this need, however, because a Taoist is actually doing something, conscious, or deliberately programmed to do it.  I'm looking of a word that describes someone who does nothing because he has been 'burned' into apathy, or lacks enough interest to even try.  I believe a Taoist has 'learned' what he is passionate about doing....